# Is there an app/script that is easy to use to make an image popup after scanning a QR code?

Tags: excel, qr-code, data-entry, paperless

I'm going to set up a system for logging scans of employee IDs, and it was requested that I make the person's image popup so that it can be seen that someone isn't just scanning someone else's ID. I'm planning to make a form in excel wherein the QR code's text will be input in a field and then it will log the person by adding an entry to a Table, and then also make the image of their ID pop up on screen.

So far I've found this: http://www.iaccessworld.com/function-open-image-file-vba/
The OpenImageFile VBA function. But that would open an image file using a specified app/executable. What I would rather happen is that there is a window containing a box and the image inside the box changes when the person scans the QR on their ID.

Digressing Rant:
Right now I am in charge of an office where I want to slowly adopt paperless processes and go digital, even if slowly, but nobody wants it so the burden is on me to implement the move to paperless.
Disclaimer: So I'm not exactly an experienced programmer but I've debugged and written some VBT(Visual Basic for Test, a derivative of VBA used in the manufacturing industry), written some VBA for excel, and written assembly for PIC microcontrollers.

Comment: Good Start, This will help you https://www.homeandlearn.org/load_an_image_into_an_imagebox.html

Comment: I just want to say thank you. I used the article in the link it is working right now.